# How to Parse KML file in android and display it in Google maps?

Tags: android, kml

i'm trying to parse KML file in android apps.
that's use in Google Map for placehold.
anyone has idea to solve reply me.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
KmlLayer layer = new KmlLayer(mMap, kmlInputStream, getApplicationContext());
```

kmlInputStream means result of kml url or file.

Comment: shall we put raw file in place of kmlOnputStream like layer = new KmlLayer(mMap,R.raw.direction, this);

Comment: i am not sure. try it. if in case fails please use fileinputstreamreader to read row file. or else place row file in devide memory and read it and diplay in may.